# Dell Display Manager

Tags: display, dell, monitor

How can I get my Dell Monitors software i.e. Dell Display Manager in my Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS for controlling the monitor via software rather than the physical buttons on the screen ?

Comment: Most likely you can't if Dell doesn't provide software for Linux.

Comment: The answer is here... You can't use that particular software, but Linux has it's own way. https://askubuntu.com/questions/860761/ubuntu-command-line-to-change-input-source-on-a-display-monitor

Comment: As the previous comment hints, one can write a Gnome extension that uses ddcutil for controlling specific things in the screen. For example, there is one for controlling brightness: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2645/brightness-control-using-ddcutil.

Comment: Dell also build their SDK for linux, e.g. https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/drivers/driversdetails?driverid=0p8mg
But getting your hands on the latest binaries isn't easy, and the lib is basically same as ddcutil but with all the dell specific enums and the dell specific apis.

Answer (score 3):

The proprietary application called *Dell Display Manager* has not been provided for Ubuntu. However, most displays (including Dell’s) can be controlled from the PC over [DDC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel) communication which is available in Ubuntu.

### Brightness

If you wish to control the display’s brightness, use the GNOME extension [Brightness control using ddcutil](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2645/brightness-control-using-ddcutil/). Setting it up, however, requires several steps. Apart from [installing the extension](https://wiki.gnome.org/action/show/Projects/GnomeShellIntegration/Installation) (which requires a browser addon and a native application or manual installation), you must [setup `ddcutil`](https://github.com/daitj/gnome-display-brightness-ddcutil/blob/master/README.md#setup-ddcutil) which is used as a backend of this extension.

I’ve installed the extension together with `ddcutil` and it’s worth it from my perspective.

[image: screenshot of running brightness extension]

### Other controls

If you wish to control other features of your display, you should follow the [manual approach using `ddcutil`](https://askubuntu.com/a/1251533/250300) (or `ddccontrol` but it’s [outdated](https://www.ddcutil.com/ddccontrol/)) or create/find a wrapper appropriate to your needs.

### Related questions

- [Ubuntu command line to change input source on a display monitor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860761/ubuntu-command-line-to-change-input-source-on-a-display-monitor)
- [How to change external monitor brightness via DDC/IC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218993/how-to-change-external-monitor-brightness-via-ddc-ic)

Answer (score 0):

Installing ddcutil with Gnome extension related to it works in my case.

1. Install ddcutil

> ```
> sudo apt update && sudo apt install ddcutil
> ```

2. follow the instructions in the Readme file of the official git repo
   [Setup ddcutil](https://github.com/daitj/gnome-display-brightness-ddcutil/blob/master/README.md#setup-ddcutil)
3. Install the Gnome extension. [Brightness control using ddcutil](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/2645/brightness-control-using-ddcutil/)
4. Reboot and check

[image]