# Some applications open on turned off display

Tags: multiple-monitors, display, hdmi

I have tv on HDMI-0 and main display on DP-2.

When I turn off tv, some applications like image browser, still open on tv even when it is turned off.

I need sth like run automatically `xrandr --output HDMI-0 --off` when I turn off tv.

And also bring back settings for `Joined Displays` when I turn tv on.

For settings I mean to have tv on the left.

For some reason Ubuntu always treats tv as main display and that it is on the right.

I want tv to be on the left and not to be main display.

I tried https://github.com/phillipberndt/autorandr but it does not detect that tv is turned on. It probably just looks if there cable in hdmi?

This answer could provide one piece of the puzzle:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433203/how-to-determine-if-lcd-monitor-is-turned-on-from-linux-command-line/3461971#3461971

And similar question 
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/302995/how-to-detect-if-hdmi-monitor-is-switched-off-in-ubuntu

I tried to use `xset -q` to get information if display is turned on, but it only shows my main monitor.

`xrandr` shows that tv is connected, but no info about it being powered off.

I see there is https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/MonitorDetection but I don't know what to use.

UPDATE:

`sudo ddccontrol -p` does not list my tv.

[Ubuntu command line to change input source on a display monitor?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/860761/ubuntu-command-line-to-change-input-source-on-a-display-monitor)

UPDATE2:

`hwinfo` does not list my tv.

UPDATE3:

So I have these two scripts:

to turn off:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
intern=DP-2
extern=HDMI-0

xrandr --output "$extern" --auto --left-of "$intern" --output "$intern" --auto --primary
```

to turn on:

```
#!/bin/bash
intern=DP-2
extern=HDMI-0

xrandr --output "$extern" --off
```

So now the question is how to detect that tv is turned off.

UPDATE4:

Now I see `xrandr -q` gives different results when tv is turned off:

```
$ xrandr -q | grep "^HDMI-0"
HDMI-0 connected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
$ ~/bin/xrandr_auto_external_monitor.sh
$ xrandr -q | grep "^HDMI-0"
HDMI-0 connected 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 1872mm x 1053mm
```

But probably I cannot get the event when tv is turned off manually?

> when you manually switch of the the monitor, you cant catch it by windows (if there is no unusual driver interface for this), because all windows capabilities is connected to "power safe mode".

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203355/is-there-any-way-to-detect-the-monitor-state-in-windows-on-or-off/613300#613300